# Why isn't a newly purchased domain showing up in Google searches?

Tags: google, domains

The domain ...

`http://trello.com`

... was purchased a few months ago and is now live as of a week or so ago -- and has been linked from several prominent places on the web -- but searching for the word `trello` produces absolutely no results from `http://trello.com` in Google whatsoever.

We know that most of the pages are being indexed by google, for two reasons:

1. Google Webmaster Tools says the site is fine
2. If you do a search including site:trello.com in the search terms, plenty of pages come up

Is it because most of the page content on the site is generated on the fly via JavaScript, or because there needs to be some kind of special support for the googlebot agent?

We're at a loss to explain why this is happening.

Comment: trello in Greek means crazy. Did you know that? :P

Answer (score 30):

Per [Google's Matt Cutts](http://twitter.com/#!/mattcutts/status/118431538995142657), the answer is **the `trello.com` domain had been parked for years, so it was on a Google Long Term Parked Domains blacklist.**

This somehow prohibited it from showing up in search results at all.

Apparently [Google has some changes coming to fix this problem](http://twitter.com/#!/mattcutts/status/118432235853586432), but until then, Matt Cutts [advises](http://twitter.com/#!/mattcutts/status/118433097258778624):

> If you're going to launch something new on a multi-year parked domain, have a pre-launch stub or "coming soon" page.

Basically, force the parked domain to have some kind of HTML change a few months in advance to give Google the signal that this long term parked domain is now coming back to life.

Comment: Just wanted to inform that `https://trello.com/` shows up second in the google search after `www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2011/09/13.html`. I am located in UAE, but I am using `google.com` as my search domain.

Comment: I see the site in my search results on google.co.uk too.

Comment: @CodeCanvas, Disgruntledgoat: Google has fixed the issue for this domain apparently; yesterday trello.com didn't show up for me, now it does.

Comment: https://trello.com/ is showing up 3rd for me when I Google it from the US. A post from Joel's site and from Life Hacker about the service are the only ones that show up in front of it for me.

Comment: It's already been fixed (by google, on their side)

Comment: It shows up just after Joel on Gogole Singapore. Btw, I presume you did the standard SEO friendly stuff, like submitting to Open Directory (+ search engines)? If so, just wait and it will soon be top - but make sure that it stays there.