# New domain and submission to search engines

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, domain-registration

I have registered a new domain with a hosting company. They offer the feature that for each new domain there is an associated placeholder page. Actually it is a "Site not configured page" with some technical text and links to the hosting site.

I could:

1. submit its URL to search engines right now
2. remove the page and submit the URL when the site will be online (could be a couple of months)
3. replace the default page with "coming soon" contents and submit the URL
4. opt for simplicity and add a blank html page having a focused and well descriptive title and maybe some meta tag
5. other?

I prefer 4 over 3 because at the moment there aren't precise project details to provide.

What's the proper way to notify search engines that soon this site will be online, without getting penalized for side effects I'm not considering or aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following question may help: [Why isn't a newly purchased domain showing up in Google searches?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20147/why-isnt-a-newly-purchased-domain-showing-up-in-google-searches)

The best solution for a new domain is not to park it but create a basic "coming soon" page. You don't need a lot of detail, anything relevant is great, e.g. the site name and what it's about, maybe an image or logo.

There is no way to specifically tell search engines to "check back soon". And there's no real need to submit to search engines, just link to the site from elsewhere shortly before or once it's opened.

Answer (score 2):

Submitting your site to a search engine before your site has content is like raising your hand in class when you don't have an answer. Sure, you're letting them know that you're there, but they don't know how to evaluate you. My advice is to create a "Coming Soon" page- but more than that, be sure to edit the **title** and **meta** tags with something relevant to your site. This won't give you a ton of SEO points, but it's better than a blank page (or God forbid a "Site not configured" page). Good luck!