# SEO actions on a new domain that has only a launch page, for better future results?

Tags: seo

I have bought a domain name for a website I will create in the next few months. I am really concern about the SEO for this new page.

So, the launch page has a very good SEO score but my question is, what actions shall I make to build earlier for the future?

Does the SEO actions are different because of a launch page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, there is very little to worry about. Make sure the domain resolves to a real web page and is not "parked". [More info here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20147/why-isnt-a-newly-purchased-domain-showing-up-in-google-searches); the solution is to put up a basic splash page that has a little information about what the site is (or will be).

The only other concern would be if you are planning thousands or millions of pages. So many new pages appearing overnight will look suspect to search engines, so it is better to launch with a few pages and add content as you go.

It's not necessary to publicise your site in this time (and risk disappointing users), Google is very good at finding new sites with few or no links pointing to them.

Comment: Pretty much this, though I would go on to add that if the site is literally just a splash page detailing what will be available in the future, you'd be fighting a losing battle to rank at this stage. Search Engines want useful content - which you don't have yet, so there isn't much you can do at the minute.

Comment: @Anonymous The point of a splash page is not to rank at all, only to avoid future problems.

Comment: I understand that, all I'm saying is SEO at this stage is a pointless consideration.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat What are the future problems?

Comment: @Kaoukkos see the link in my post :)